# How do you FIND (not prove) an expression that is logically equivalent to another expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I need to find an expression that is logically equivalent to q ↔ (¬p ∨ ¬q). I have already constructed a truth table for the expression, but it hasn't helped so I'm still unsure on how to find a logically equivalent expression. The truth table has given this output:

F
F
T
F

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not delete the contents of your question after it has received an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your truth table indicates that your expression is true in exactly one of the four cases.  That says that this expression is equivalent to one of $p \wedge q$, ${\lnot} p \wedge q$, $p \wedge {\lnot q}$, $\lnot p \wedge \lnot q$: I'll leave it to you to see which one.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I've found the answer, but I'm still unsure on how you came up with those expressions.. If you don't mind me asking, how did you know to use a conjunction ∧ and not a disjunction ∨ ? And how did you know which proposition to negate? Or did you just use trial and error?

Comment: For example, $p \wedge \lnot q$ says $p$ is true and $q$ is false.